# Getting error while running Taurus

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

i have installed taurus with the help of 'Prebuilt Installer'(http://gettaurus.org/docs/Installation/), but while executing it throws some configuration error.i am using 'bzt' command to run the taurus. Can some one take a look and answer.

Error Log:

```
12:35:42 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.7.4
12:35:42 INFO: Starting with configs: []
12:35:42 INFO: Configuring...
12:35:42 INFO: No personal config: C:\Users\zz\.bzt-rc
12:35:43 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Users\zz\2016-11-24_12-35-43.100000
12:35:43 INFO: Preparing...
12:35:43 ERROR: Config Error: No 'execution' is configured. Did you forget to pass config files?
12:35:43 INFO: Post-processing...
12:35:43 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Users\zz\2016-11-24_12-35-43.100000
12:35:43 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have executed `bzt` command without passing any arguments to it so the behaviour is absolutely expected.

If you need to run something, you need to provide either JMX script like:

```
bzt test.jmx
```

or Taurus configuration file in [YAML](http://yaml.org/) or [JSON format](http://json.org/) like:

1. Create a Taurus config file, for example:

   ```
   ---
   execution:
   - concurrency: 100
     ramp-up: 1m
     hold-for: 5m
     scenario: quick-test

   scenarios:
     quick-test:
       requests:
       - http://blazedemo.com
   ```
2. Save it as `test.yml`
3. Execute it with Taurus as

   ```
   bzt test.yml
   ```

See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) article for more details.